# SUPEE-6788 - Module Upgrades

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, supee-6788

following on from the release of the SUPEE-6788 patch I was wondering what the advised process is for those modules which have not yet been patched or updated but are vital for customer interaction & site functionality.

On one of our client websites running: https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox provides a sizeable list of modules which are not compatiable with the patch, however after updating a couple of them I have found that the module developers have not yet upgraded their modules.

In this case, what is the best practise, change the admin routing via the script and wait for the module developer to release an upgrade or completely remove the module/find an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the toolbox from Paradox labs is very helpful, do I trust it to change code on my live Magento shop - **no**.

I would use the tool to identify all the effected modules in your development environment, and then check for module updates from the module developer.

Where no update is available either take a copy of your version of the module, or clone the source files and then make your changes. If you are familiar with code management systems such as github then use this to store your master copy of the module and to manage the changes you make to it.

Once you have identified and tested all the affected modules in your development environment you can install them on your staging/live servers.

At some point the author of affected modules will hopefully update his code and you can then make the decision to revert to the authors code, or continue to maintain your version of the module.